# Understanding Async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method `void getInformation()` that calls 5 other methods of which each is getting some data from a database. It takes about 1 second until all data is collected and returned to `getInformation()` and because of that I thought I should collect the data in the background. My question is: can I just make `getInformation()` `async` so the UI isn't blocked while the other methods are collecting the information or do I have to make every of the other methods `async` ?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await getContactInformation();
}

public async Task getContactInformation()
{
  this.data.Add(collectData1());
  this.data.Add(collectData2());
  this.data.Add(collectData3());
  this.data.Add(collectData4());
  this.data.Add(collectData5());
}
```

Comment: look into this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async)

Comment: Take a look at these Q&As: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177891/can-somebody-please-explain-async-await, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960998/how-different-async-programming-is-from-threads and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/async-and-await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the ideal situation for `async` is to use "async all the way". In this case, your code would look like this:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await getContactInformationAsync();
}

public async Task getContactInformationAsync()
{
  this.data.Add(await collectData1Async());
  this.data.Add(await collectData2Async());
  this.data.Add(await collectData3Async());
  this.data.Add(await collectData4Async());
  this.data.Add(await collectData5Async());
}
```

Note that modern database APIs such as Entity Framework 6, ADO.NET, SQLite, etc, all have asynchronous APIs that you can use to implement the `collectDataNAsync` methods. This is the ideal `async` scenario, since it minimizes thread waste and also keeps the UI nicely responsive.

However, if you want more of a "quick fix", then you can push the (synchronous) calls off to a background thread, and then treat that background work asynchronously, as such:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(() => getContactInformation());
}

public void getContactInformation()
{
  this.data.Add(collectData1());
  this.data.Add(collectData2());
  this.data.Add(collectData3());
  this.data.Add(collectData4());
  this.data.Add(collectData5());
}
```

This would solve your immediate problem (freeing up the UI thread) at the expense of a thread pool thread. It's not *ideal* but it would work.

Comment: The API I'm using doesn't provide async methods but thanks for the advise

Answer (score 2):

In general I would recommend all IO to be taken off the UI thread, but there is no point in making each individual call `async`.

For guidance on the effect of `async` calls on database IO blocked threads, I found this very clear and useful advice.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/11/14/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous.aspx

Comment: I think too making every call `async` is not the right solution in this case and thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

No. Your method body has to use an await or you'll get a warning.

Easy enough.

Wrap your method body with...

```
await Task.Run(()=>{
// do your thing
});
```

Comment: You mean in `//do your thing` should be the data-collect-calls and I'll be fine?

Comment: Yes. Replace that with your normal synchronous code for it to be run on a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks @DanielKelley for the edit. Written from memory, could use factory.startnew in place of run.

Comment: How do I handle "not all code paths return a value" when doing it like this?

Comment: Put async in the method declaration before the task return type.  Public async Task GetInformation()

Comment: Well, my real code returns an ArrayList, so I have `public async Task<ArrayList> doSomething()` and I return an `ArrayList` in `await Task.Run(() => { // returning here });`

Answer (score 1):

> can I just make getInformation() async so the UI isn't blocked while the other methods are collecting the information or do I have to make every of the other methods async ?

The latter. When you go `async` it is *"async all the way"*, meaning you make `async` method calls all the way to the top of your stack. For IO bound operations, there isn't a need to use background threads, since most APIs these days expose `XXXAsync` method calls which are truely asynchronous, which means your UI message loop is free to process other messages while the IO request executes.

An important thing to note though is that marking a method `async` is not enough to make it asynchronous. You actually have to `await` an async operation, such as your database method call. If there's no async API call to your database, you wont be able to go async.

In you case, `getContactInformation` will make the compiler omit a warning saying you have an async method which isn't being awaited. De-Facto, if you `await getInformation()`, you will be running completely synchronously.

Comment: But if I want to make the data-collect-calls `async` too, I'd have to change my whole project. This code was just to get an idea on how to get a solution for this

Comment: The solution is to make your data-collect calls `async`. That is the primary point. If your DB calls are synchronous, how do you expect to make them async?

Comment: I was hoping for a solution where I don't have to change all method- bodys and headers, something like `BackgroundClass.doInBackground(methodCall)`, that makes the UI responsive but still executes the called method.

Comment: You *can* do this using a background thread. But, that would be waisting a completely good thread which will simply block until the IO request completes. If you need this to scale-out eventually, that wont work. I would recommend you not to do that. I think it is worth the effort to refactor your codebase to support true asynchronous calls.